# Include same code segment from another file at multiple places of single Facelet and render dyncamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm aware that there have many questions regarding similar topic, from which i understood about View Build time and View Render Time Tags, but I'm unable to find the solution for this. Please point me to right question if answered.

Consider the scenario where I have written some facelet code (a bunch of input components) written in an xhtml file. I want to include this code/set of components in another xhtml, at many places. which is explained in below image.

[image]

If user `ui:include` i'll have `Duplicate ID` issue. To come over that if I use `c:if` my `ViewScoped` bean is converted to `RequestScoped`.

Following is the code I tried.
index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="genderSelect" value="#{myBean.gender}">
        <p:ajax update="dynaPanel"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--select--" itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="m"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="f"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:panelGroup id="dynaPanel" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="malePanel" rendered="#{myBean.gender eq 'm'}">
            <h1>Male</h1><br/>

            <h:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}"/><br/>
            <ui:include src="country.xhtml"/>

        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="femalePanel" layout="block" rendered="#{myBean.gender eq 'f'}">
            <h1>Female</h1><br/>
            <ui:include src="country.xhtml"/><br/>

            <h:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}"/>

        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.action}" />

</h:form>
```

country.xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputLabel value="Country:"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="countrySelect" value="#{myBean.country}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="USA" itemValue="us"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="UK" itemValue="uk"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="India" itemValue="in"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="China" itemValue="ch"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

MyBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    private String country;
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("@PostConstruct");
    }

    public void action(){
        System.out.println(name+"-"+gender+"-"+country);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destory(){
        System.out.println("@PreDestroy");
    }

    //Setters Getters

}
```

How do I achieve this without duplicate ID issue or not compromising the `ViewScope` of my ManagedBean.

*Using JSF-2.1.13*

Comment: In my case after upgrading mojarra  jsf to above 2.2.5 this issue was solved.

Comment: Have you tried my code from the post? It's still ain't working for me with 2.2.5.

Comment: The `<c:if>` is the right answer. It indeed only kills view scoped beans in Mojarra versions before 2.1.18.

Comment: @BalusC : Oh thanks very much. I thought the fix is that, they made `ui:repeat` as view render tag, so it will be added to component tree only after evaluating (which would've been nice, just my wish!). Thanks again for clearing this :)